# Localization in box using rangefinders

Tags: localization

Let's say I have a robot, located in a box. The robot can move in the x and y and rotate.

The robot has 4 rangefinders, mounted 90 degrees apart, that measure the distance to the walls of the box (I think it would be possible with just 3 but let's use 4 as an example). The robot also has an "approximate" +-10 degree estimate of its heading, so it knows in general which quadrant its bearing should be in.

Given this information, how can I calculate the "exact" position and bearing of the robot?

Intuitively I know this should easily be possible as there are three degrees of freedom for the system (x,y, and the angle), but I can't think of a way to actually calculate the position.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your coord axis is at the center of the box and the axes parallel to the walls o the box.  Distance to the min-y-wall tells you y.  Distance to the min-x wall gives you x, with the obvious offsets added in.  Crazy-easy unless I misunderstood.